Use Google Workspace for some emails but keep my mail provider for others
I finally decided to switch my small business email to Google Workspace. However, I don't need to use it for every email account, as some of them barely have any use and many are forward only, so I want to keep many of them on the regular Dreamhost mail and use them with IMAP or POP3 as I do now.
My question is, how do I set the MX records for some of the email addresses, but not for all? Because for each address that I add on Workspace, I have to pay the monthly fee, so naturally I just want to do those for the actual main adressess that we will be using.

You can't split a domain across different MX hosts. You may be able to forward emails from one of the providers to the other.

Email addresses for a single domain can't be separated to different mail servers using MX records.
One solution might be to use a subdomain e.g. user@mail.example.com, but if they are existing emails that might be impractical.
There is an app available in the marketplace that will "Auto forward email messages from Gmail to any other email address" that might help too.
